# Express.js and form validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm tring to create a simple node- with express.js script that will sum 3 numbers.

On index I have this:

index.jade

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title Test
  body
    form(name='form1', method='post', action='/')
      label(for='1')
      input#1(type='text', name='1')
      label(for='2')
      input#2(type='text', name='2')
      label(for='3')
      input#3(type='text', name='3')
      input(name='submit', type='button', value='submit')
    #result
```

and also i'm now writing the serverside - app.js with req and res object but how to return a result... also result = 1id + 2id + 3id

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
    app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var i = req.param('1', null);
  var j = req.param('2', null);
  var k = req.param('3', null);
  var r = i+j+k;
  res.send(r);

});
```

How I to send results (r) into div id Result on index.jade... so how to return result to index.jade

also here is pastebin code: http://pastebin.com/J9MRFCaE ... i'm new to node and express and sorry for stupid question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, just call your "index.jade" rendering passing your data (instead of 'res.send(r);') :

```
res.render('index', { 
  result: r
});
```

And display "result" variable in your jade file :

```
#result #{result}
```

Additional information on [jade code](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#code) and [express rendering](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering)

Comment: i only get Cannot Get/ message ... WHY THAT?

Comment: You must declare two routes : one with app.get('/', req,res) which will only call res.render('index') and one with app.post('/',req,res) which will do the computation and call res.render('index', {result:r})

Comment: Well, I am in my bed writing from my iPhone. Check the express documentation I linked in my answer, everything you need is in it.

Comment: Explainations : you setup the 'classic' route to you index '/' on HTTP GET method for normal displaying of the page (when user type the address in browser or follow a link...) plus you had a route on the same URL ('/') but on the POST method (basic http) for when use submit the form. In that case you not only render the page but also retrieve data, compute the result and pass it to the renderer

Comment: what that means: Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Comment: It means exactly what's written : jade is based in indentation, you can not use both space and tabulation to indent your template.

Comment: what that measns now: ReferenceError: C:\Users\PC\glowing-frost-5319/views/index.jade:14
    12. '      input#3(type=\'text', name='3')
'
    13. '      input(name=\'submit', type='button', value='submit') 
'
    14. '    #result #{result}'

result is not defined

Comment: This is not a correct way to proceed on StackExchange + stucking on such clear, explained errors shows you don't know much about what you're dealing with. Please take time to read documentation and tutorials I linked. Last help on this error : the renderer seems to stuck on '#result #{result}' line in the template ? You got that ? Then, it tells you "result is not defined". Isn't it self explanatory ? It's because you didn't pass any result value when you called the render engine. Two options : pass a value when you call the rendering engine or test the value within the template.